# My Python Scrapy cannot scrape out the "keyword" content

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I cannot scrapy the "keyword" content. >"<
I've tried many methods but still failed.

I've successfully retrieved other contents, but still failed to get the "keyword" content.

Can anyone help to fix this bug?? 
The keyword content is located at "#keyword_table a",
or XPath "//*[@id="keyword_table"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"

Picture of the keyword content:

[image]

My code:

```
import scrapy 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from digitimes.items import DigitimesItem


class digitimesCrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'digitimes'
    start_urls = ["http://www.digitimes.com.tw/tw/dt/n/shwnws.asp?id=435000"]


def parse(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body,'html.parser')
    soupXml = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "lxml")
    simpleList = []

    item = DigitimesItem()

    timeSel=soup.select('.insubject .small')   
    tmpTime = timeSel[0].text
    time = tmpTime[:10]
    item['time'] = time #處理完時間啦
    print(time)

    titleSel = soup.select('title')
    title = titleSel[0].text
    item['title'] = title #處理完時間啦
    print(title)

    #================== To Resolve ==================

    keywordOutput="" 
    for k in soupXml.select('#keyword_table a'):
        for key in k:
            keywordOutput = keywordOutput + key + " "
    item['keyword'] = keywordOutput 
    print(keywordOutput)

    #================== To Resolve ==================



    categoryOutput=""
    for m in soup.select('#sitemaptable tr td a'):
        for cate in m:
            if(cate!="DIGITIMES"):
                categoryOutput = categoryOutput + cate + " "
    item['cate'] = categoryOutput  
    print(categoryOutput) 

    simpleList.append(item)
    return simpleList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are using BeautifulSoup over scrapy selectors? Response your method receives already acts as a scrapy selector which can do both xpath and css selections.

There seems to be 3 keywords in the table. You can select them with either xpath or css selectors:

```
response.css("#keyword_table a::text").extract()
# or with xpath
response.xpath("//*[@id='keyword_table']//a/text()").extract()
# both return
>>> [u'Sony', u'\u5f71\u50cf\u611f\u6e2c\u5668', u'\u80a1\u7968\u4ea4\u6613']
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've learnt to use BeautifulSoup from online course~ I will go to check the original selector in the scrapy~~ Thank you!!